# Magento 2: How to add customer grid in custom module tab?

Tags: magento2, module, customer-grid

I want to add customer grid in custom module's tab in Magento 2.1
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow Step to add the customer grid in tab.

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Tabs.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit;

class Tabs extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('page_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Notification Information'));
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {   
        $this->addTab('customergrid', array(
            'label'     => __('Customers'),
            'title'     => __('Customers'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('JT\PushNotification\Block\Adminhtml\Notification\Edit\Tab\Customers')->toHtml(),
        ));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

> ```
> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Customers.php
> ```

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab;

class Customers extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'customer/customers.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
     */
    protected $blockGrid;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * AssignProducts constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve instance of grid block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getBlockGrid()
    {

        if (null === $this->blockGrid) {
            $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'VendorName\ModduleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\CustomerGrid',
                'customer.grid'
            );
        }
        return $this->blockGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Return HTML of grid block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {

        return $this->getBlockGrid()->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomersJson()
    {
        $notificationId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('notification_id', false);
        $customers = [];
        if($notificationId) {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $collection = $objectManager->create('VendorName\ModuleName\Model\NotificationQueue')->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('notification_id', ['eq' => $notificationId]);
            if ( $collection->getSize() > 0 ) {
                foreach ($collection as $notification) {
                    $customers[$notification->getCustomerId()] = '';
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($customers)) {
            return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($customers);
        }
        return '{}';
    }

}
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/CustomerGrid.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab;

/**
 * Class Porders
 * @package VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab
 */
class CustomerGrid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    protected $_objectManager = null;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerCollection,
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerCollection
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customerCollection = $customerCollection;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * _construct
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $notificationId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('notification_id',0);
        $this->setId('customerGrids_'.$notificationId);
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * add Column Filter To Collection
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_customer') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedCustomers();

            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
            } else {
                if ($productIds) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * prepare collection
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->customerCollection->getCollection();
        $collection->setOrder('entity_id','DESC');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_customer',
            [
                'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_customer',
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedCustomers(),
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'firstname',
            [
                'header' => __('Firstname'),
                'index' => 'firstname',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'lastname',
            [
                'header' => __('Lastname'),
                'index' => 'lastname',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'email',
            [
                'header' => __('Email'),
                'index' => 'email',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('notification/index/customergrid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param  object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return '';
    }

    protected function _getSelectedCustomers()
    {
        return $this->getCustomerIds();
    }

    protected function getCustomerIds()
    {
        $notificationId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('notification_id', false);
        $customers = [];
        if($notificationId) {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $collection = $objectManager->create('VendorName\ModuleName\Model\NotificationQueue')->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('notification_id', ['eq' => $notificationId]);
            if ( $collection->getSize() > 0 ) {
                foreach ($collection as $notification) {                    
                    $customers[] = $notification->getCustomerId();
                }
            }
        }
        return $customers;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/CustomerGrid.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;

class CustomerGrid extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $_resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\Customers');

        return $resultLayout;
    }

}
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates/customer/customers.phtml

```
<?php
$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();
?>
<?php  echo $block->getGridHtml(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="notification_customers" id="in_customers" data-form-part="edit_form" value="" />
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "VendorName_ModuleName/js/customer/customers": {
                "selectedCustomers": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCustomersJson(); ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}'; ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- @todo remove when "UI components" will support such initialization -->
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/notification_index_customergrid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\CustomerGrid" name="notification.customers.grid"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/customer/customers.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/* global $, $H */

define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedCustomers = config.selectedCustomers,
            notificationCustomers = $H(selectedCustomers),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;

        $('in_customers').value = Object.toJSON(notificationCustomers);

        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryProduct(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    notificationCustomers.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
                notificationCustomers.set(element.value, '');
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                notificationCustomers.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('in_customers').value = Object.toJSON(notificationCustomers);
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_products[]': notificationCustomers.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function categoryProductRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change product position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                notificationCustomers.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('in_customers').value = Object.toJSON(notificationCustomers);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryProductRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                position = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];

            if (checkbox && position) {
                checkbox.positionElement = position;
                position.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                position.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                position.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(position, 'keyup', positionChange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryProductRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryProduct;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryProductRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

After doing all above things run all commands once and check.

Please let me still if you get any error.

Thanks.